# Using Laravel, is there a way to check which database I'm connected to and change to another?

Tags: laravel

If I'm doing something simple like

```
Auth::user()->username
```

Is there a way I can change the database that I'm getting this information from?

I already have the other database connection information entered in the database.php file. Just not sure how to change it on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

**DB SETUP**

```
'mysql2' => array(
    'read' => array(
        'host' => '192.168.1.1',
    ),
    'write' => array(
        'host' => '196.168.1.2'
    ),
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'database'  => 'database',
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => '',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
),
```

**In your AUTH driver specify the DB to use**

*app/config/auth.php*

```
'driver' => 'database',
```

for diff table than `users`

```
'table' => 'administrators',
```

Create your own driver

http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/115/using-your-own-authentication-driver

Comment: I'd like to be able to change the database on the fly. Going back and forth between 2 or more databases.

Comment: Ah, you'd have to write your own AUTH driver

Comment: Is there an easy way to just change the database that I currently want to use?

Comment: You could just MYSQL JOIN the data for the Auth

Comment: Maybe a little more info will help. Basically I have 2 databases. The 'users' db and the 'cards' db. I'd like to set the cards db as default in database.php but I'd like to use users for authentication and other stuff.

Comment: I think you are saying the wrong words here you mean you have two different **tables**?

Comment: No, it's 2 different databases. They have different tables in them.

Comment: Honestly I don't know how to do that.  If I were you id tell mysql to create a master users table.  And just whenever a record is inserted in either table it copies the data into the master table.